# Reduce function push into array value

Tags: javascript, reduce

**I have array of objects:**

```
const items = [{ search_type: 'environment',
    search_code: 'TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
  { search_type: 'environment',
    search_code: 'TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00003',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'scene',
    search_code: 'TBA_SCENE00006',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
 ];
```

**and would like to return something similar to this:**

```
{
ASSET00002: {
   environment:["TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002"],
   job:["TBA_JOB00002"],
   scene:["TBA_SCENE00006"]
},
ASSET00004: {
   environment:["TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002"],
   job:["TBA_JOB00002","TBA_JOB00003"]
},
}
```

Here I used this logic using Reduce function:

```
const result = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const { search_type, search_code, asset_code } = item;
  return {
    ...acc,
    [asset_code]: {
      ...acc[asset_code], [search_type]: [search_code]
    },
  };
}, {});
```

**I am getting the following result:**

```
{
ASSET00002: {
   environment:["TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002"],
   job:["TBA_JOB00002"],
   scene:["TBA_SCENE00006"]
},
ASSET00004: {
   environment:["TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002"],
   job:["TBA_JOB00003"]
},
}
```

Here on return "ASSET00004"-> "job" i supposed to get array with two value but got only one .
I know there is some missing on my code, but could not find the way to properly push value into array.
Any help would be appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by a single `reduce` method, making sure that you add on to any existing array as you iterate through the objects:

```js
const items = [{ search_type: 'environment',
    search_code: 'TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
  { search_type: 'environment',
    search_code: 'TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00003',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'scene',
    search_code: 'TBA_SCENE00006',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
 ];

const assets = items.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc[el.asset_code]) {
    acc[el.asset_code] = {};
  }
  acc[el.asset_code][el.search_type] = 
    [...acc[el.asset_code][el.search_type] || [], el.search_code];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(assets);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, because of this line

```
[asset_code]: {
 ...acc[asset_code], [search_type]: [search_code]
},
```

you are losing the context of the previous values stored in the search_type array and it is taking only the latest value you pushed to it.

We need to check whether already array key is already present in the object and if it is not present, create a new array or if it is present, push it to the same one.

The code can be modified like as given below.

```
const result = items.reduce((acc, item, i) => {
  const { search_type, search_code, asset_code } = item;
  return {
    ...acc,
    [asset_code]: {
      ...acc[asset_code],
      [search_type]: acc[asset_code] && acc[asset_code][search_type] ?
       acc[asset_code][search_type].concat([search_code]) : [search_code]
    }
  };
}, {});
```

In the above code, we are checking whether the values are already present in the array and concatenating it if present.

Answer (score 0):

So you are not adding anything to the `search_type` key.

The code below uses spread operators to add to the array.

```js
const items = [{ search_type: 'environment',
    search_code: 'TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
  { search_type: 'environment',
    search_code: 'TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00003',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'scene',
    search_code: 'TBA_SCENE00006',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
 ];
/*

{
ASSET00002: {
   environment:["TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002"],
   job:["TBA_JOB00002"],
   scene:["TBA_SCENE00006"]
},
ASSET00004: {
   environment:["TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002"],
   job:["TBA_JOB00002","TBA_JOB00003"]
},
}*/

const res = items.reduce((acc, {asset_code, search_type, search_code}) => ({
  ...acc,
  [asset_code]: {
    ...acc[asset_code],
    [search_type]: [
      // this is where you add to your array, this doesn't guarentee uniqueness however
      ...(acc[asset_code] && acc[asset_code][search_type] || []),
      search_code
    ] 
  }
}), {})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Non ES6 solution.

```js
const items = [{ search_type: 'environment',
    search_code: 'TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
  { search_type: 'environment',
    search_code: 'TBA_ENVIRONMENT00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00002',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'job',
    search_code: 'TBA_JOB00003',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00004' },
  { search_type: 'scene',
    search_code: 'TBA_SCENE00006',
    asset_code: 'ASSET00002' },
 ];


  var result = {};
   items.forEach( function (item) {            
      result[item.asset_code]  = result[item.asset_code] || {};
      if(result[item.asset_code][item.search_type]){
        result[item.asset_code][item.search_type].push(item.search_code);
      }else{
        result[item.asset_code][item.search_type] = new Array(item.search_code)
      }
   });

   console.log(result);
```